# Three stage amplifier

Tags: amplifier

Well I need to design three stage amplifier
[image: The Stages of Amplifier]

Im stuck on the output stage, I need that the AC Current on the load will between 20mA to 100mA, but Top current I get is almost 5mA, cant over pass it with use of 12V Vcc. What im Missing?

[image: The original circuit]

[image: The current output]

EDIT:
Redesigned it and now Im gettin 40mA. 
Thanks for the HELP GUYS!

[image: Curcuit after redesign]

[image: Ac current]

My mistake, putting too large load.

Comment: Do you know the ohm's law?  6V/1kΩ = 6mA

Comment: Do you recognize that the output is clipping? This indicates your input signal is too large.  To get 100ma peak through 1K Ohm load will require a supply voltage of 100V supply and a 100V peak to peak input signal. Or you could drop the load to 120 Ohms and get 100mA peak.

Comment: Please dont' remove the question when it gets answered; leave the question there and add the additional details afterward, so that someone else with the same problem can see what you were asking.

Comment: Please realize that by editing your figures, you make it impossible to figure out what the problem was. In the future,  edit your question to add the solution rather than replacing the original.

Comment: @Hearth ok, I edit it back with the original circuit and problem!!

Answer (score 0):

Are you driving to drive a 1k ohm load with 100 ma?  That requires 100 volts. You need to rethink your requirements. The 100 ohm resistors in the output stage alone will drop 10 volts at 100 ma. A 12 volt supply is inadequate for this application.